# Can $x^{x^x}=k$ be solved using the W function?

Tags: lambert-w

The lambert W function is defined to be the inverse of $f(x)=xe^x$, and the equation $x^x=k$ can be solved fairly easily using the function:
$$x^x=k$$
$$\ln(x^x)=\ln(k)$$
$$x\ln(x)=\ln(k)$$
$$e^{\ln(x)}\ln(x)=\ln(k)$$
$$\ln(x)=W(\ln(k))$$
$$x=e^{W(\ln(k))}$$

My question is, can $ x^{x^x}=k$  be solved using the lambert W function, and if so, can power towers of any height be solved using some iterative process?

Comment: You've made an unediable (edit too short) typo. $x\ln(x) = \ln(k)$.

Answer (score 2):

```
can $x^{x^x}=y$ be solved using the lambert W function, and if so,
```

Using Maurer's notation, the equation ${^n}x=y$ is solvable using Lambert's $W$ function only for $n=2$.

If we loosely define "transcendence degree of an equation" to be the height of the highest exponential tower with $x$ on top, contained in the equation minus one, then $W$ solves ONLY equations with (transcendence) degree at most 1 (that is, with exponentials of total height 2), but NOT all such equations.

The equation $x^{x^x}=y$ is written as ${^3}x=y$, consequently it has (transcendence) degree 2 (tower with 3 x's minus 1)

If memory serves right, the most general equation solvable by $W$ is something like:

$$a\cdot x^m\cdot d^{b\cdot x^n+c}=y$$

which as you can see can be reduced to having degree 1 at some point in the algebraic solution process, by taking $n$-th roots on both sides of the equation.

Elaborating on the second point, note that adding one plain $x$ to the equation above and it fails solvability. That is, the equation

$$a\cdot x^m\cdot d^{b\cdot x^n+c}+x=y$$

for example, is now NOT solvable by $W$, although it is of the same transcendence degree as the one above, so the definition of "transcendence degree" of an equation, needs to be made a liitle more rigorous, by specifying some additional configuration constraints, which vary from case to case.

```
can power towers of any height be solved using some iterative process?
```

Sure they can. Omitting details about existence, the following equivalence holds:

$${^n}x=y\Leftrightarrow x=^{\frac{1}{n}}y$$

and this is the $n$-th order super root of $y$, which, after taking care of domains and ranges, can be approximated using backwards numerical iteration.

Such a method, for example, was presented in Maple by Robert Israel, above, long time ago on sci.math.

Comment: You just pretty much stated that it cannot solve equations with a transcendence degree of higher than one, but is there any reason/proof of why?

Comment: @ASKASK Sure: It's because the Lambert is the inverse of $x\cdot\exp(x)=y$ and not the inverse of some $x\cdot \exp^{(n)}(x)=y$, with $n>1$. Isn't it obvious that the limitation comes from the definition of $W$?

Comment: Well actually you can solve $x^{x^{x+1}} = a$: write this as $y^y = a$ where $y = x^x$, and use Lambert twice.

Comment: @ioannisgalidakis I still don't see what your point is... just because the definition only has n=1, why does that mean that it can't solve equations of higher n? Robert Israel provided a good counterexample.

Comment: @ASKASK Yes, Robert gave an excellent counterexample. Maybe he is hinting towards a stronger definition than what I called "transcendence degree" by showing a certain pattern in the grouping of the power tower, which allows $W$ to be applied iteratively all the way down to a closed form solution. Which, if true, would be wonderful.

Comment: I don't think I was hinting, but now that you mentioned a pattern, I suppose it would be 
$$\eqalign{&x\cr &{x}^{x}\cr &{x}^{{x}^{1+x}}\cr &{x}^{{x}^{1+x+{x}^{1+x}}}\cr
&{x}^{{x}^{1+x+{x}
^{1+x}+{x}^{1+x+{x}^{1+x}}}}\cr &{x}^{{x}^{1+x+{x}^{1+x}+{x}^{1+x+{x}^{1+x
}}+{x}^{1+x+{x}^{1+x}+{x}^{1+x+{x}^{1+x}}}}}}
$$
where each expression is obtained by substituting $x^x$ for $x$ in the previous one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes. Barring now such special groupings of the power tower, do you (or anyone else) perhaps know of a more general form of solvables than the first equation I gave above (for height 1)?