# Lambert W function in solving repeated exponentiation

Tags: special-functions, lambert-w

Is there any manipulation for the equation $x^{x^x}=c$ to be presented in a tractable Lambert-W-function form? I'm certain that $x^x=c$ is possible.

Comment: Indeed $x^x=c$ is solved by $$x=\frac{\ln(c)}{W(\ln(c))}$$ I don't think there is any such expression for $x^{x^x}=c$ though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can $x^{x^x}=k$ be solved using the W function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035539/can-xxx-k-be-solved-using-the-w-function)